# How to avoid deadlock in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am facing problem in scenario where user points are getting deducted from the database table and at the same time when request came for adding the points that points are not getting added due to deadlock condition. I need advise to avoid the deadlock. I cannot make code threadsafe as it will affect the processing. I am using Postgres as database.

Answer (score 3):

If the deadlock happens only occasionally, don't worry. Just repeat the transaction.

If it happens often, you have to do more to get decent performance. There are two measures to reduce the frequency of deadlocks:

- Keep the transactions short and don't add or delete more points in one transaction than necessary.
- Whenever you modify more than one point in a transaction, handle (and thus lock) the points in some fixed order, for example in the order of the primary key column.